# Automatically create Timer in Netbeans

Tags: mysql, netbeans, timer

I am creating a school web application that gets information from a MySQL database. I want the back-end to regularly delete entries with time stamps that have already expired in the database.

From what I researched, I created a TimerSessionBean with the Schedule annotation for every hour to delete entries from the database. For testing sake, right now I am simply trying to get the bean to print something ever 5 minutes. This is what I have so far:

```
import javax.ejb.Schedule;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import java.util.Date;

@Stateless
public class TimerSessionBean {

    @Schedule(minute = "*/5")
    public void PrintTime() {
        System.out.println("Current: " + new Date());
    }
}
```

However, nothing happens when I deploy my application. Is it not enough to just create the TimerSessionBean and include the Schedule annotation?

Answer (score 0):

TimerSessionBean is a singleton session bean that shows how to set both an automatic timer and a programmatic timer.
In the source code listing of TimerSessionBean that follows, the setTimer and @Timeout methods are used to set a programmatic timer.
A TimerService instance is injected by the container when the bean is created. Because it’s a business method, setTimer is exposed to the local, no-interface view of TimerSessionBean and can be invoked by the client.

In this example, the client invokes setTimer with an interval duration of 30,000 milliseconds.
The setTimer method creates a new timer by invoking the createTimer method of TimerService.
Now that the timer is set, the EJB container will invoke the programmaticTimeout method of TimerSessionBean when the timer expires, in about 30 seconds.

[Using the timer service](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html)

```
package timersession.ejb;

import java.util.Date;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.Schedule;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ejb.Timeout;
import javax.ejb.Timer;
import javax.ejb.TimerService;

@Singleton
public class TimerSessionBean {
    @Resource
    TimerService timerService;

    private Date lastProgrammaticTimeout;
    private Date lastAutomaticTimeout;


    public void setTimer(long intervalDuration) {
        System.out.println("Setting a programmatic timeout for "
                + intervalDuration + " milliseconds from now.");
        Timer timer = timerService.createTimer(intervalDuration, 
                "Created new programmatic timer");
    }

    @Timeout
    public void programmaticTimeout(Timer timer) {
        this.setLastProgrammaticTimeout(new Date());
        System.out.println("Programmatic timeout occurred.");
    }

    @Schedule(minute="*/5", hour="*")
    public void automaticTimeout() {
        this.setLastAutomaticTimeout(new Date());
        System.out.println("Automatic timeout occured");
    }

    public void setLastProgrammaticTimeout(Date lastTimeout) {
    this.lastProgrammaticTimeout = lastTimeout;
    }

    public void setLastAutomaticTimeout(Date lastAutomaticTimeout) {
    this.lastAutomaticTimeout = lastAutomaticTimeout;
    }
 [...]
```

To see the output `JAVA Console` must be open.

Comment: Thank you for the info, but is there a way to to get it to print without having the client invoke the timer? I need to have the back-end regularly remove stuff from the database regardless of anyone using the web application.

Comment: Do it outside of netbeans. Deploy it with the admin console (4848)  and start the server with auto start when booting the computer.

Comment: I see, so there is no way for the timer to automatically start. But what about your automaticTimeout method? My understanding is if you give the Schedule annotation, it should immediately start the timer when you deploy the project.